# TxTextControl Using the numbering tool numbers blank lines

Tags: txtextcontrol

Using the numbering tool numbers blank lines

Add two lines of text with a blank line in between.

Highlight text and click the numbering tool

**Expected**

1.Sample 1

2.Sample 2

3.Sample 3

**Actual**

1.Sample 1

2.

3.Sample 2

4.

5.Sample 3